# Grails & AspectJ: advice for private methods is not working

Tags: spring, grails, aspectj, spring-aop

I need to intercept calls to private methods in Grails services. The following aspect IS working for any annotated public methods, however nothing happens when the annotation is at PRIVATE methods.

```
import exceptions.DwcpExeption
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggerInterceptor {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerInterceptor.class);
    @Around("@annotation(newAnnotation)")
    public Object aroundEvents(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, NewAnnotation newAnnotation) {
        log.info newAnnotation.value()
        String logMessage = String.format("%s.%s(%s)",
                proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName(),
                proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                Arrays.toString(proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()));
        log.info "*Entering $logMessage"
        def result
        try {
            result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()
        catch (ex) {
            log.error '', ex
        }
        log.info "*Exiting $logMessage. Result: $result"
        return result
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem is in config? I've tried in applicationContext.xml
`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`
and in resources.groovy
`aop.config("proxy-target-class": true)`

Nevertheless, only public methods are intercepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the scope it defaults to public. Add a pointcut for private methods:

```
@Around("@annotation(newAnnotation) && execution(private * *(..))")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Even with @Around("execution(private * *(..))"). What else could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you use Spring AOP, not full-fledged AspectJ. See my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Spring AOP is a proxy-based "AOP lite" approach in comparison to AspectJ. It only works for Spring components and only for public, non-static methods. This is also explained in the [Spring AOP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) as follows:

> *Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods only!*
>
> *If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.*

Bottom line: Please switch to AspectJ which can be easily integrated into Spring applications via LTW (load-time weaving) as described in [Section 9.8, “Using AspectJ with Spring applications”](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: I knew that, that's why I thought using annotations from aspectj packages will be enough for aspectj to kick in. But it's not realy the case, is it? Do I understand it correctly that in order to use aspectj, the javaagent is required?

Comment: Yes, for LTW you need the weaving agent. You can also use CTW (compile-time weaving) during the build process, then the smaller AspectJ runtime on the classpath will be enough.